# Update input field on checkbox selection with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like two things to happen.

One

> when a selection is made the input field updates as the total,

Two

> the check boxes are dynamically generated and may sometimes be up to
>   six and sometimes as low as one product.

This is what I have made, but I can't get it to work :(

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateTotal(){
        document.getElementById('total').value = 
            (document.getElementById('date0').checked?
             parseFloat(document.getElementById('date0').price):0) +
             (document.getElementById('date1').checked?
             parseFloat(document.getElementById('date1').price):0) +
             (document.getElementById('date2').checked?
             parseFloat(document.getElementById('date2').price):0);
    }
    </script>
```

With this as form

```
<form>
 <td id="datecontainer" onchange="Process(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
   <input id="date0" type="checkbox" name="form[date]" value="blue" price="10" onChange="javascript:updateTotal();">product 1<br />
   <input id="date1" type="checkbox" name="form[date]" value="green" price="30" onChange="javascript:updateTotal();">product 2<br />
   <input id="date2" type="checkbox" name="form[date]" value="red" price="50" onChange="javascript:updateTotal();">product 3<br />
 </td>
 <td>
  Total cost is:
  <input name="total" id="total" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="border:0px;">
 </td>
</form>
```

Any help will be great!

Comment: would you provide a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net , it would be easy to check it in realtime and update as necessary...

Comment: Well it does not work, that is why I am asking help, but here you go [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FF33T/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by changing your code and markup as follows:

**HTML**

```
<td id="datecontainer" onchange="Process(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
   <input id="date0" type="checkbox" name="form[date]" value="blue" data-price="10" onChange="updateTotal();">product 1<br />
   <input id="date1" type="checkbox" name="form[date]" value="green" data-price="30" onChange="updateTotal();">product 2<br />
   <input id="date2" type="checkbox" name="form[date]" value="red" data-price="50" onChange="updateTotal();">product 3<br />
 </td>
 <td>
  Total cost is:
  <input name="total" id="total" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="border:0px;">
 </td>​
```

**JS**

```
function updateTotal(){
    var date0 = document.getElementById('date0');
    var date1 = document.getElementById('date1');
    var date2 = document.getElementById('date2');
    var amount = 0;    
    amount += date0.checked ? parseFloat(date0.getAttribute('data-price')) : 0;
    amount += date1.checked ? parseFloat(date1.getAttribute('data-price')) : 0;
    amount += date2.checked ? parseFloat(date2.getAttribute('data-price')) : 0;
    document.getElementById('total').value = amount;

}​
```

A couple of things to note:

You do not need to include the javascript: before the function in the onchanged attribute.
You should prefix custom attributes with the data-* prefix.
You should surround your td tags with tr and table.  The way that you are using them it would make more send to use an ul tag with li children.

**DEMO** - http://jsfiddle.net/9mxh5/

***If the checkboxes are dynamically generated and you don't know how many you may have:***

**HTML**

```
<td id="datecontainer" onchange="Process(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
   <input id="date0" type="checkbox" name="form[date]" value="blue" data-price="10" onChange="updateTotal(this);">product 1<br />
   <input id="date1" type="checkbox" name="form[date]" value="green" data-price="30" onChange="updateTotal(this);">product 2<br />
   <input id="date2" type="checkbox" name="form[date]" value="red" data-price="50" onChange="updateTotal(this);">product 3<br />
 </td>
 <td>
```

**JS**

```
var amount = 0;

function updateTotal(element){
        var price = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('data-price'));
        amount += element.checked ? price : price*(-1);
        document.getElementById('total').value = amount;

    }​
```

**DEMO** - http://jsfiddle.net/9mxh5/2/